# Customizing models in Sylius. Doctrine Error: Property "translations" in "AppBundle\Entity\Product" was already declared

Tags: doctrine, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to customize the Product Model in Sylius based on this documentation page: [Sylius Customization Guide: Customizing Models](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html).

In AppBundle I created my own class Product:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;

/**
 * Class Product
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_product")
 */
 class Product extends BaseProduct
 {
    ...
 }
```

But when I run

```
 $ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get this error:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                        
 Property "translations" in "AppBundle\Entity\Product" 
 was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override config for your model. Add this to your configuratioN

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
```